# Save 404 Error's URL in Django in models

Tags: django, django-models, http-status-code-404

I figured it would be useful to collect all 404 errors and store them in a model.

These errors can/should be useful in writing (or re-writing) urls for designing a new web project. Also, as you might do, people who automatically type in `http://www.domian.com/news` or `http://www.domian.com/products`or `http://www.domian.com/facebook`

It would also be useful when people type links in incorrectly and you can develop a redirect for it.

I just don't know how I would execute something like this. Any ideas?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to write custom middleware that handles 404s. See the Django [documentation on middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).

A very simple example middleware class that triggers on a 404:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

class Catch404Middleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseNotFound):
            print "That was a 404!"
        return response
```

Remember you'll need to install this class into your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py.

Comment: Looks easy enough. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a previous answer, I've made this:

```
#middleware.py (Under the Analytics App)


from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound, HttpRequest
from analytics.models import Site_Error

class Catch404Middleware(object):
     def process_response(self, request, response):
         if isinstance(response, HttpResponseNotFound):
        try:
            new_save,created = Site_Error.objects.get_or_create(error=request.path)
            new_save.times += 1
            new_save.save()
        except:
           new_save = False
    return response

#models.py (Ananlytics App)

class Site_Error(models.Model):
    error = models.CharField(max_length=8000)
    times = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
         ordering = ('-timestamp',)
         verbose_name = "Error"
         verbose_name_plural = "Errors"

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.error


#in settings.py 
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
'analytics.middleware.Catch404Middleware',
)
```

This code will save all requested paths into the `Site_Error` model. There is much more you can do with this so I suggest you look in [Django documentation on middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) just as recommended by an answer before.